# Periodic MySQL lockup when Wordpress is under heavy load

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a MySQL 5.1.61 database running behind two load balanced Apache webservers hosting a fairly busy (100K uniques per day) Wordpress sites. I'm caching with Cloudflare, W3TC, and Varnish. Most of the time, the database server handles traffic very well. "show full processlist" shows 20-40 queries at any given time, with most being in the sleep state.

Periodically, though (particularly when traffic spikes or when a large number of comments are cleared), MySQL stops responding. I'll find 1000-1500 queries running, many "sending data", etc. No particular query seems to be straining the database (they're all standard Wordpress queries), but it just seems like the simultaneous volume of requests causes all queries to hang up. I'm (usually) still able to log in, to run "show full processlist", or other queries, but the 1000+ queries already in there just sit. The only solution seems to be to restart mysql (sometimes violently via kill -9 if I can't connect).

All tables are innodb, server has 8 cores, 24GB RAM, plenty of disk space, and the following is my my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port=3306
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
user=mysql
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=16M
wait_timeout = 300
query_cache_size=128M
key_buffer_size=400M
thread_cache_size=50
table_cache=8192
skip-name-resolve
max_heap_table_size = 256M
tmp_table_size = 256M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
innodb_log_file_size=1G
#innodb_commit_concurrency = 32
#innodb_thread_concurrency = 32
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
thread_concurrency = 8
join_buffer_size = 256k
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
#innodb_concurrency_tickets = 220
thread_stack     = 256K
max_allowed_packet=512M
max_connections=2500
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

#2012-11-03
#attempting a ram disk for tmp tables
tmpdir = /db/tmpfs01

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Any suggestions how I can potentially improve MySQL config, or other steps to maintain database stability under heavy load?

Comment: There is ofc always room for MySQL configuration improvements, but the first thing which pops into my mind is caching. Have you already some caching method in use? For WordPress, I'd recommend http://ocaoimh.ie/wp-super-cache/. This dramatically reduces load to your database.

Comment: Bjoerm-I'm using varnish to cache for Apache, and W3TC to cache Wordpress itself. The caching has helped tremendously (particularly Varnish), but I still get hit with these "deadly embraces" every day or two.

Comment: You could try raising the query cache limit to 32 MB or even 64 MB, if you think it is the database which is responsible for this load problem. However, try to think out of the box. Maybe another server process, probably not even directlry related to the database (a backup job, virus scan, whatever), is eating away some of your ressources and slowing down your databases performance. I've had a similar situation not too long ago, and it turned out to be a high prioritized `logrotate` was the source of it.

Comment: MySQL 5.5 includes a number of significant performance improvements. Have you tried testing against that version to see if it could help with this situation? You should also check the errata on later versions of 5.1 to see if this is a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Is there a reason you have the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set to use only 5GB of ram? If MySQL is the only thing on this machine (which is hopefully the case), you should set it to be 70-80% of RAM to fully utilize your hardware. For more tuning, check out: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/

Comment: You can identify the cause of your queries waiting by using `show engine innodb status`. Especially look into transaction area and into last detected deadlock. Usually in these cases, you have a common table locked out completely by a query, leading to query accumulation and mysql becoming unresponsive.

Comment: Do you have any very long comment threads, e.g. 5K+ comments per post? I discover that one of the things Wordpress doesn't do very well is comment pagination: even if pagination is turned on, [it loads all of them into memory](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8071). I fixed this manually in my theme, by copying the offending function and adding in `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses. (This won't explain the lockups, but if it applies to you then dealing with it will at least help you reduce db load).

Comment: 11 years later! Greetings @EvilPluto what was your resolution to this issue you were facing?

Comment: Updating `innodb_buffer_pool_size` solved this issue for us...

Answer (score 1):

Like has been said, think outside the box and do sone rooting around why these queries are slow or somehow hung. An oldie but a good source of problems even for (supposedly;) intelligent system engineers is load balancing causing issues across webserver or database sessions. With all that caching and load balancing going on, are you sure everything is always connecting end-to-end as intended?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with alditis & Bjoern

I'm pretty noobish with mysql but running mysqltuner can reveal some config optimisations based on recent queries of the DB https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl

And if possible store the DB files on a physically separate partition from the OS, the OS can consume IO which slows the DB. Like with Bjoern's logrotate issue.

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at basic system behavior at the moment of problems. Use both vmstat and iostat if you can find any issues. See if the system starts swapping (pi,po columns in vmstat) and if lots of IO is happening. This is the first step in debugging your problem.

Another source of useful information is SHOW INNODB STATUS. See for http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/ on how to interpret the output.

It might be that at a certain point in time your writes are killing read performance because they flush the query cache.